# Is there a way to break out a row if it meets a certain value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

For example, let's say there's a table like this:

```
ID        Food
--        ----
1         Fruit
```

So whenever it says Fruit, I want to break it out into 3 rows:

```
ID       Food
--       ----
1        Apple
1        Banana
1        Orange
```

Any tips?

Comment: Look at your post and ask yourself if you think you would be able to answer this based on what you posted. You need to provide some actual details of what you want. Is this in a query? Or are you trying to take any row that is fruit and turn it into 3 rows in the table? Where do the new values come from? Give us something and we can help.

Comment: create a table indicating what a fruit is and join this table on the same id´s

Comment: I'd create a [one-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) in your database. Create a second table that looks like `(ID, FoodId, FoodPartName)`

Comment: Although creating a table with the defined values would be easier, I'd like to avoid creating a new table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You could do:

```
select t.id, coalesce(a.alt, t.food) as food
from t outer apply
     (select alt
      from (values ('Apple'), ('Banana'), ('Orange')) v(alt)
      where t.food = 'Fruit'
     ) a;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this worked perfectly for me! Can I ask what the v(alt) part means? Does that part put the values into alt?

Comment: @Marco . . The `v` is a table alias (just like `a`).  The `alt` provides a column name in an analogous fashion.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, Food FROM YourTable WHERE food <> 'Fruit' 
UNION 
select ID, f2 FROM YourTable JOIN 
    (SELECT'Apple' f2 
        union 
        SELECT 'Banana' f2 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'ORANGE' f2
    ) DT 
        ON food = 'Fruit'
```